# In Java, when I declare a variable final static just like "final static int a;", is a protected or public?

Tags: java

In Java, when I declare a variable final static just like "final static int a;", is "a" protected or public?

Comment: When you don't write the modifier it is 'default'. Neither protected nor public.

Comment: @sn42 I got it! I mixed default access specifier up with protected. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ParthLukhi I got it. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

When you don't specify an access modifier, it is always `default` modifier. Default modifier means the field will be accessible from inside the same package to which the class belongs. Checkout some examples of `default` modifier [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers)

Comment: I got it! Thanks! I mixed default modifier up with protected.

Comment: I think the default is also named "package", no? Meaning that its scope is for the current package. Here's a more official link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html